# Given xpath expression "//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]" is invalid with Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

After upgrading from version 2.53 to version 3.14 Selenium says

`Given xpath expression "//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]" is invalid`

This code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver/v0.23.0");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
//...
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
WebElement loaderElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]"));
```

produces this error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression "//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x8060000d (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPath :: line 401"  data: no]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: '10.233.112.79', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-116-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 64.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 2736, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.OP8KKQ..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.4.0-116-generic, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace

```
//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]
```

with

```
//div[contains(@class, 'loader-overlay')]
```

Note that you should use `[@attr = "value"]` syntax if you want to check if *attribute value is exactly the `"value"`*, but `contains` syntax is `[contains(@attr, "value")]`

Comment: Note that it's a common error to think that contains(NODE, 'str') tests whether the content of NODE is 'str', whereas it actually tests whether the content of NODE contains 'str' as a substring.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression "//div[contains(@class='loader-overlay')]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x8060000d (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPath :: line 401"  data: no]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

...implies that that the *xpath expression* was not a valid one.

### Solution

If the element is having a single **class** *attribute* as **`loader-overlay`** you need to change the *xpath* as:

```
"//div[@class='loader-overlay']"
```

If the element is having multiple **class** *attributes* and **`loader-overlay`** is one among them you need to change the *xpath* as:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'loader-overlay')]"
```